# Convert list of string dictionary to another dictionary using python 2.7 and print in tabular format

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, formatting

Here's the data that I have:

```
['{"end_date":"2021-07-15 09:00:00","number":"CHG81923","requested_by":"Dan","cmdb_ci":"LR Resort"}','{"end_date":"2021-07-15 06:00:00","number":"CHG13146","requested_by":"Tery","cmdb_ci":"My Service"}']
```

Actual result needs to be in tabular form by formatting the above content. There is limitation in using Pandas and `ast` module.

How can I print the result like this?

```
End Date                Number       Requester      CMDB
2021-07-15 09:00:00     CHG81923     Dan            LR Resort
2021-07-15 06:00:00     CHG13146     Tery           My Service
```

Answer (score 0):

try `pandas` for simplicity

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

data = ['{"end_date":"2021-07-15 09:00:00","number":"CHG81923","requested_by":"Dan","cmdb_ci":"LR Resort"}','{"end_date":"2021-07-15 06:00:00","number":"CHG13146","requested_by":"Tery","cmdb_ci":"My Service"}']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map(json.loads, data))
df.rename(columns={
    'end_date': 'End Date',
    'number': 'Number',
    'requested_by': 'Requester',
    'cmdb_ci': 'CMDB'
}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```
              End Date    Number Requester        CMDB
0  2021-07-15 09:00:00  CHG81923       Dan   LR Resort
1  2021-07-15 06:00:00  CHG13146      Tery  My Service
```

To save as csv use

```
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

### UPDATE

```py
import json
d = ['{"end_date":"2021-07-15 09:00:00","number":"CHG81923","requested_by":"Dan","cmdb_ci":"LR Resort"}','{"end_date":"2021-07-15 06:00:00","number":"CHG13146","requested_by":"Tery","cmdb_ci":"My Service"}']

data = [json.loads(i) for i in d]
headers = ['End Date', 'Number', 'Requester', 'CMDB']

max_column_heights = [max(map(len, i))+5 for i in zip(*[i.values() for i in data], headers)] #+5 for extra space

for each_row in [headers] + [i.values() for i in data]:
    for column, i in enumerate(each_row):
        print(i.ljust(max_column_heights[column]), end='')
    print()
    
    
    
# End Date                Number       Requester     CMDB           
# 2021-07-15 09:00:00     CHG81923     Dan           LR Resort      
# 2021-07-15 06:00:00     CHG13146     Tery          My Service
```

Comment: Any suggestions, how can we do the same without using third party module like pandas or others?

Comment: can you use `json` module?

Comment: Yes I can use json module.

Comment: It throws  error.

`Exception during execution:
javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression in <script> at line number 7 at column number 83`

NOTE: I am using python 2.7.   Sorry to say but the tool I am using support python 2.7 only. Your input is welcome.

Comment: from where does `javax` comes not sure, and I wrote it for python 3.6+ not sure about 2.7, not tested

Comment: just to add the tool I am using provides interface for running jython script(where we can run standard python script as well) which is based on jython 2.7.2 standalone. That might be the limitation because it is v2.7.2.